# Zalando Postgres-Operator Topic

Tags: database, postgresql, operators

Is there any way to login into the database cluster of zalando postgres-operator from outside of the Cluster and also can we  migrate our existing databases to the zalando postgres-operator

if yes could some one provide me the details or exact links so That I can check the process

answers and links for the above questions